# How to write an update SQL statement to update multiple records

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have this code so far, which reads a simple table with 3 varchar fields:

```
<?php
//db connection code...

// select database 
mysql_select_db($db) or die ("Unable to select database!"); 

// create query 
$query = "SELECT * FROM Sheet1"; 

// execute query 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error());

// see if any rows were returned 
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
// yes

// see if any rows were returned 
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
// yes 
// print them one after another 
echo "<html><body><table cellpadding=10 border=1>"; 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td>".$row['stickerID']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" .$row['stickerName']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>".$row['stickerSection']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>"?>
             <form name="some form" action="editform.php" method="post">
             <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $row['stickerID'] ?>" value=" <?php echo $row['stickerStatus'] ?> ">
             <?php "</td>";
    echo "</tr>"; 
}
echo "</table></body></html>";
echo " " ?>
             <input type="submit" name="editWish" value="Edit">
             </form>
             <?php " ";
} else {  
// no 
// print status message 
echo "No rows found!"; 
}  

// free result set memory 
mysql_free_result($result); 

// close connection 
mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

The database has 4 fields, 3 varchar and 1 int with current value of 0. I checked the page source code and confirmed each checkbox name is the stickerID.  Now I will post this to the editform.php which I must create.  What Im wondering is how should I write the update sql so that it takes into account each new value selected by the user in the form?

This is my idea, but how to I do it for every checkbox?

editform.php

```
<?php

//update multiple records

//UPDATE user_items SET stickerStatus = $_POST["stickerStatus"] WHERE stickerID = $_POST["stickerID"];

?>
```

Comment: On a unrelated note, what is the <center> tag doing in the middle of your table? Doesn't seem to be valid html to me. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question: use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysql_fetch_row()`. That will return an associative array instead of an enumerated one.

Second question: read up on [HTML forms](https://www.google.nl/#q=HTML+forms) and [form handling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php).

The answer to the question in the comments:

```
// The <form> tag should only be echoed once.
echo '<form name="some form" action="editform.php" method="post">';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td>".$row['stickerID']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" .$row['stickerName']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>".$row['stickerSection']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>"?>
             <input type="hidden" name="status_<?php echo $row['stickerID"; ?>" value="0">
             <input type="checkbox" name="status_<?php echo $row['stickerID'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['stickerStatus'] ?> ">
             <?php "</td>";
    echo "</tr>"; 
}
// You need a submit button to send the form
echo '<input type="submit">';
// Close the <form> tag
echo '</form>';
```

Using a hidden input with the same name as the checkbox makes sure a value for the given input name is sent to the server. The value of a checkbox that's not checked will not be sent. In that case the hidden input will be used.

You can get the submitted values in editform.php as follows:

```
<?php
foreach ($_POST as $field => $value) {
    if (strpos($field, 'status_')) {
        // Using (int) makes sure it's cast to an integer, preventing SQL injections
        $stickerID = (int) str_replace('status_', '', $field);
        // Again, preventing SQL injections. If the status could be a string, then use mysql_real_escape_string()
        $stickerStatus = (int) $value;

        // Do something with the results
    }
}
```

Comment: The keys of `$row` have changed from numerical to actual field names, so you should update the rest of the script accordingly. That _was_ your first question after all...

Comment: Ok thx!  How do I insert the checkbox though?  I updated my question code with what I tried and I get a blank page.

Comment: Updated the answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
print_r($row)
```

to find out exactly how your row arrays are constructed and work from there.

For your comparison operator, use

```
$row[3] === 0
```

instead of

```
$row[3] == 0
```

This will return true if both the value and data type match rather than just the value.

0 can mean the Boolean false aswell as the numeric value 0